# Is there a quick way to find out how many words I've written altogether in my posts?

Tags: feature-request

Is there a quick way to find out how many words I've written altogether in my posts on EL&U?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the SQL from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008509/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-words-in-a-string-in-oracle) on Stack Overflow, I've put together a word count query on the latest data dump on the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/398004/how-many-words-have-i-written-all-together?UserId=76472).

There is not a way to see it in "real time" on the site. The data dump is updated regularly every Sunday.

Comment: Thanks Matt, you're a star.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for ELL?

Comment: It works for me. What is your ELL user ID?

Comment: *Sheepish smile* Oops, I just repeated my EL&U ID... I thought the username is the same, so  the number must be as well. I now realize that would be pretty stupid, if I belong to ten different SE  communities, I can't have the same ID.